# Jquery Show / Hide toggle not working on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive-design

Glad to be on Stack Overflow. I'm new to JS /Jquery and can use HTML/CSS and have managed to piece together the following code.

It's for a box with an expand button that upon clicking shows / hides a slider panel under it.

It works on desktop but doesnt not work on smartphones (Tested on iPhone5 with Chrome & Safari up to date versions.

Can you please guide me as to why this is not functioning at all on the mobile?

Thanks
Vila

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

---

```
<div id="card_bg">
    <p class="hero_text">We love design</p>
    <p class="sub_text">We love design</p>
    <p class="link showSingle" id="2">EXPAND &gt;</p>
    <div class="share_sheet_2 collapse_share"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
#card_bg {
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 4px 8px -2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width:320px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) linear-gradient(transparent 50%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%) repeat-x scroll 50% 100% / 2px 2px padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgba(55, 70, 72, 0.8);
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: rgba(55, 70, 72, 0.8) none 0px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.hero_text {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 55px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.sub_text {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #535860;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.link {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #535860;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.link:hover {
    color: green;
}
.collapse_share {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 60px;
    display: none;
    height:54px;
    background-color: green;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 9px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 9px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 9px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
.share_icons {
    width: 20%;
    height: 54px;
    float:left;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.ico_padding {
    width: 20%;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 14px;
}
```

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".showSingle", function () {
        $('.showSingle').toggleClass('hide');
        var index = $(this).attr('id');
        newTarget = $('.share_sheet_' + index).slideDown('fast');
        $('.collapse_share').not(newTarget).slideUp('fast');
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".collapse_share", function () {
        $('.collapse_share').slideUp('fast');
        $('.showSingle').removeClass('hide');
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".hide", function () {
        $('.collapse_share').slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Try using `return false;`.

Comment: use same css both for desktop and for mobile?

Comment: Hi @Velthune, Yes, using the same css for desktop & mobile.

Comment: Hi @SreekeshOkky, could you advise where I should insert the return: false; code in the JS?

Comment: To prevent issues caused via event bubbling

Comment: @SreekeshOkky I tried using the return false, but it isn't working unfortunately. But it is working only if I use input type = button instead of P class. Any clue why?  #jquery #javascript